# Exporting FileGeodatabase Subtypes to Excel

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, excel

I'm working with a large file-geodatabase(100 layers) and need to create an excel spreadsheet listing all the subtypes with values and labels extracted. Is there a way to do with this task with out of the box tools or does a script need to be created?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap to try to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this automatically is using Arcpy. First thing to do is extract all Feature Layer names from the GDB using **arcpy.ListDatasets**. Then use those feature layer names to extract subtype names and details by using **arcpy.da.ListSubtypes**. It can become tricky so it need a good understanding of Python data storage and a good debugger.